# How to get the singular value of a 2-by-2 matrix?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, singular-values

I am going to get the principal angles between 2 subspaces in $\mathbb{R^4}$ according to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102153) hint. The 2 matrices involved are $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \\ c & -d \\ d & c \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} e & -f \\ f & e \\ g & -h \\ h & g \end{bmatrix}$ respectively. Evaluating $A^T B$ yields $\begin{bmatrix} ae + bf + cg + dh &  -af + be - ch + dg \\ -be + af - dg + ch & ae + bf + cg + dh \end{bmatrix}$ which is already quite messy. So is there a quick way to find out $\sigma(A^T B)$, in particular the larger one, considering $A^T B$ is only a $2 \times 2$ matrix? Thanks in advance.

Edit: if I further simplify the notations, then $A^T B$ yields $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & -\beta \\ \beta & \alpha \end{bmatrix}$ and I got the singular values to be $\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$ unless $\alpha = \beta = 0$. Would anyone help verify this?

Comment: there is a closed form for the svd of a 2x2 matrix, albeit it is not especially pleasant, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Calculating_the_SVD

Comment: If the columns are orthogonal (which your simplified version seems to indicate, but I di not check your calculation), then yes, the singular values are given by the Euclidean norms of the columns.

Comment: Use the well-known equivalence of these matrices with complex numbers. E.g. $A \sim (u,v)^T$ with $u = a + ib, v = c + id$ etc.. This is a ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and a subspace of $2 \times 2$ matrices, which will simplify your algebra quite a bit.

Comment: But I was really confused when my professor claim I made something wrong during this calculation. I hope it is not because I constructed A and B wrong.